# Are there tags to specify the Google +1 story format in Google+ like og-meta for Facebook?

Tags: facebook-like, google-plus-one, schema.org, og-meta

With `Facebook` we have the [`Open Graph tags`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) that allow webmasters to specify how the story is displayed on Facebook.

Is there something similar for the `Google +1` button, that allows webmasters to specify the thumbnail image, description and title? `Google+` seems to be ignoring the `og-meta tags`.

[image: Example of Google's Profile +1 list, versus Facebook's wall]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From **Google+** help docs, we now have an **official answer**.

Google uses [schema.org](http://schema.org/) microdata to generate rich snippets in search (and in Google+). There's a lot written about schema.org and how it relates to Facebook OpenGraph in these two links:

See: http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=1211158
See: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/

**Some important bits:**

> **+Snippet**
>
> After +1'ing a page, the user is given the option to share the page to
>   Google+ via a displayed **Share bubble**. This share bubble (along
>   with the resulting Google+ activity post) **includes a preview, or
>   +Snippet**, that contains the page title, a brief description of the page, and a thumbnail image. These pieces of data are extracted from
>   the target URL's content in one of four ways, listed in order of
>   precedence:
>
> **Schema.org microdata (recommended)**
>
> If the page is annotated with **schema.org** microdata, the +Snippet
>   will use the `name`, `image`, and `description` properties found on
>   any schema.org type.

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="image-url"></img>
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```

> **Open Graph protocol**
>
> If the page contains Open Graph properties for the title, image, and
>   description, then they will be used for the +Snippet.

```html
<meta property="og:title" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:description" content="..."/>
```

> **Meta "title" and "description" tags**
>
> If the page's  element contains  and
>    tags, the +Snippet will use their
>   content attributes for the title and description, respectively. For
>   the thumbnail image, the sharebox will attempt to find a suitable
>   image on the page.

```html
<meta name="title" content="..." />
<meta name="description" content="..." />
```

Answer (score 12):

If I share a link to our webapp (restorm.com) in Google+ then the title, description and image are taken from the respective `og:` tags (`og:title`, `og:description`, `og:image`).

These tags

```html
<title>One Shot Orchestra • Electronic • Music, Concerts & More &#8226; restorm.com</title> 
<link href="https://restorm.com/favicon.ico?116a158" rel="shortcut icon" /> 
<meta name="description" content="Listen to music of One Shot Orchestra for free and browse the Artist's news, events, videos, pictures, shop, booking &amp; press Infos, live footage &amp; much more on restorm." />

<meta property="og:title"        content="One Shot Orchestra" />
<meta property="og:url"          content="https://one-shot-orchestra.restorm.com/" />
<meta property="og:type"         content="band" />
<meta property="og:description"  content="Bangin´ Live Electro aus Bern-Kreuzberg" />
<meta property="og:site_name"    content="restorm.com" />
<meta property="fb:app_id"       content="127577323959237" />
<meta property="og:language"     content="en" />
<meta property="og:image"        content="https://assets3.restorm.com/resources/images/40/40b17a53aa9785fa89c15b06b9fcfd72_643969.jpeg?116a158" />
<meta property="og:video"        content="https://one-shot-orchestra.restorm.com/minipage/minipage.swf?applicationSettingsURL=https%3A%2F%2Fone-shot-orchestra.restorm.com%2Fminipage%2Fsettings.xml&amp;auto=true" /> 
<meta property="og:video:width"  content="300" /> 
<meta property="og:video:height" content="200" /> 
<meta property="og:video:type"   content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
```

end up being shared like this

[image: screenshot of sharing result]

So the title and description are definitely taken from `og:title` and `og:description`, and not from the title and description meta tag...

Comment: I'd just like to comment that putting content attributes before property names is horrible style.

Comment: Have og tags on my webpage. Faceebok loads it with no problem, but google plus one doesnt.

Answer (score 4):

Images that are too small or not square enough will not be included in the +Snippet, even if explicitly referenced using schema.org microdata or Open Graph markup. Specifically, the height must be at least 120px, and if the width is less than 100px, then the aspect ratio must be no greater than 3.0.

Answer (score 3):

Just answered this on another post [Google +1 Generated Thumbmail in Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628201/google-1-generated-thumbmail-in-profile/6679700#6679700)

Looks Like Google+1 has the following data hierarchy:

1. **Open graph tags** http://ogp.me/ - seems at the moment the only way to add the thumbnail is to use the og:image tag
2. **Normal meta tags** i.e title, description
3. **Page content** if there's no description set in the above options then the description is taken from the content on the page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I am working on this, and Google+ wasn't picking up my OG tags.

When I put: `<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">` into the HTML it started to pick them up.

Hope this saves someone some time!

Answer (score 2):

meta og:image works, secret is to have image large enough. It failed at 140x112 and work when I change to bigger thumbnail 511x364

Comment: That is an interesting discovery, that it depends on the image size. Are you sure they were the same format? PNG? JPEG? GIF?

Comment: It has to be at least 120 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Google appears to be using the Title and Description of the page, in standard meta tags. It seems to have no way of specifying a thumbnail, however.

Comment: That's not true, there are ways to specify a thumbnail.

Comment: Go on, then, Artem - educate us.

Comment: OK, as mentioned above, og:image works just fine on G+ shares. If you need proof of that, check out any post page on http://www.androidpolice.com which is where I implemented them. Note that these have to be in the <head>, otherwise they don't work (from what I remember). You can test by pasting any post link into the G+ share box and seeing what happens (without og:image it pulls up some random header background element).

Comment: I just had a look at http://www.androidpolice.com/ and you aren't using og:image anymore