# FB, TWITTER,G+ share url and fixed preview image

Tags: url, twitter, google-plus, sharing, facebook-sharer

i have these simple social sharing links:

```
FB share link
     <a href="#" class="share-fb" onclick='window.open( "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://mysite.org", "myWindow", 
                  "status = 1, height = 300, width = 600, resizable = 0" )'></a>

TWITTER share link
<a href="#" class="share-tw" onclick='window.open( "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?url=http://mysite.org", "myWindow", 
              "status = 1, height = 300, width = 600, resizable = 0" )'></a>
GOOGLE PLUS
 <a href="#" class="share-g" onclick='window.open( "https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://mysite.org", "myWindow", 
              "status = 1, height = 300, width = 600, resizable = 0" )'>
             </a>
```

these links opens up a popup window where to share the page link.

What i would like is to `add a fixed site image preview` for each of the links user gonna sharing.

How can i add the preview image , fixed , foreach (FB,TWITTER, G+) of them?

NB: with preview image i mean the one showed in this photo (next to the link www.google.it):

[image]

For the FB sharer i tryed :`<meta property="og:image" content="URL of your image" />`

but it doesn't seems to work

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the sharer.php to work you should fill in some more Open Graph Tags. Take a look at this site: http://ogp.me/

You can always test your site in the Facebook Debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug
The debugger also shows warnings/errors, so it´s perfect for testing.

Twitter does not have images. Well, that´s not correct, you have to create a "Twitter Card" for your page. That is explained here: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/cards

About Google+, this should work:

```
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.....">
```

(Compare here: http://www.google.com/intl/en/webmasters/+1/button/index.html)

Also take a look at this thread: [Google +1 Generated Thumbmail in Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628201/google-1-generated-thumbmail-in-profile)

Comment: don't know why but **<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/rock.jpg" />** this doesn't works for me , maybe cause i'm not including fb api? i just use sharing urls on a links

Comment: did you try the link with the facebook debugger? it might tell you what´s wrong with the image. make sure that it´s minimum 200x200 pixels btw.

Comment: oh great ok, just i'm sharing **google.it** link so i think the image should be related to the shared link, is it true?

Comment: well, it could be possible that the image has to be on the same server, but i doubt that, to be honest...but: you should use an absolute url in the metatag (http and stuff).