# sharing contents of a flash website in google plus

Tags: facebook, flash, actionscript-3, share

What I'm trying to do is to share (video) link, description and thumbnail of the link from/of my flash website in google plus. Since main .swf file of the flash site is embedded in the single html file, it is not possible to use different meta data for different posts. So is there any way that I can share the links with related description and thumbnail image in google plus just like in facebook. 
(http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=test&p[summary]=test&p[url]=http://www.testurl.com&p[images][0]=http://www.testurl.com/images/thumb1.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For Your Informatio, sharer.php was deprecated by Facebook some time ago, it's going to be pulled at any moment.  I would suggest changing over to the like button as Facebook suggests before your code stops working.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Google+ relies on metadata in the physical page to pick up the title, description, and thumbnail image.

What I would do is to add a query string parameter to the url sent to Google+, like so:
http://www.example.com/?video=videoID

When Google then fetches the page to retrieve the metadata, you dynamically provide the correct information using the specified micro-formats or meta tags as detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8295748/354167

Additionally, you could (should?) use the query string to actually load up the relevant video in your swf, providing a better user experience.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // GOOGLE +
    private function shareGoogle(e:Event):void
    {
        openPage("https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/?v=compose&content="+escape(videoInfo.videoLink),"_popup");
    }
```

[Here](http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_Create_Social_Sharing_Buttons_with_AS3-19461.html) are the more description.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this one is not helpful enough. I've already tried as you mentioned.