# Google Plus share not picking meta tags from head

Tags: share, google-plus, meta-tags

I am trying to implement Google Plus share on my page but instead of picking title from meta tags it is picking page title from url in share dialog title. Do I need to include anything else?

```
    <meta property="og:title" content="Title"/>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Description"/>

    <a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url={google.com}"/>Link</a>
```

Comment: Hi, similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536213/are-there-tags-to-specify-the-google-1-story-format-in-google-like-og-meta-for, check here

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page in question?

Comment: I figured it out. Google Plus picks up meta tags if I share the current page URL, but if I try to share some other URL it picks up page title from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Google Developer Site, the example code snippet for Google Plus shared links is:

```html
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="{image-url}" />
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```