# Google+ Share Not Picking up Meta-Data, but Facebook and LinkedIn do. Why?

Tags: google-plus, meta, microdata

For the record, I just tried [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010723/google-plus-share-not-picking-meta-tags-from-head) Even though the documentation says the schema microdata isn't neccesary anyway.  I've tried a number of different placements and types for the microdata, and I still can't get anything to show up in the Google snippet.

And again, facebook and linkedin seem to be doing their jobs on the same page...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Reviews for John W. Smith, Profession: DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


<meta itemprop="name" content="John W. Smith (Profession: DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC)">
<meta itemprop="description" content="Rate and review Maine licensed professionals and discuss occupational licensing regulation in Maine. Rate - and debate regulations for - doctors, lawyers, massage therapists, funeral directors, land surveyors, social workers, and more.">
<meta itemprop="image" content="http://www.mainelicensereview.com/imgs/mlr3.png">


<meta name="description" content="Rate and review Maine's licensed professionals and discuss occupational licensing regulation in Maine. Rate - and debate regulations for - doctors, lawyers, massage therapists, funeral directors, land surveyors, social workers, and more.">
<meta name="keywords" content="Professional, Licensing, Reviews, Maine, Regulation, PFR, DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC, CHIROPRACTIC"><meta property="og:site_name" content="Maine License Review: Rate Licensed Professionals and Discuss Professional Licensing Laws" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.mainelicensereview.com/licensee.php?licpage=2805" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.mainelicensereview.com/imgs/mlr3.jpg" />
<meta property="og:title" content="John W. Smith (Profession: DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC)" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Milton Friedman said having a license is no assurance of quality. At Maine License Review, rate the quality of any licensed professional in Maine. Barbers, massage therapists, doctors, lawyers...Review professionals and the laws that govern their professions, costing you money and others their jobs." />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="618089658327157" />
<meta property="og:type" content="profile" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />


<!-- Google First Snip -->
<link rel="canonical" href="http//www.mainelicensereview.com/licensee.php?licpage=2805" />
```

Then I have later:

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
```

And later:

```
<img itemprop="image" src="/imgs/mlr3.png" />
```

And later:

```
<h1 itemprop="name">John W. Smith</h1>
```

And later:

```
<h3 itemprop="description">DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC</h3>
```

Comment: Still no idea what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The google structured data tester is [here](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) and should show a full breakdown of the form of structured data, not just the search engine parts you currently see. Facebook is using the og: meta tags for Open Graph, but it's the structured data this is the problem. You must put the **itemscope** and **itemtype** *before* any itemprop can be used.

Best practice is to avoid using meta tags for information which will already be in the page -  and ideally only use them to clarify confusing information like formatting of dates. After stating which Thing you will use (a Person) you wrap it with a  instead wherever it appers. So removing the microdata from the  and moving it to

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person">
<h1 itemprop="name">John W. Smith</h1>
<h2>Qualifications</h2>

<h3 itemprop="description">DOCTOR OF CHIROPRACTIC</h3>
<img src="photo.jpg" itemprop="image" alt="Photo of John W.Smith"/>
<span itemprop="jobTitle">Professor</span>
<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
<span itemprop="streetAddress">
  20341 Whitworth Institute
  405 N. Whitworth
</span>
<span itemprop="addressLocality">Seattle</span>,
<span itemprop="addressRegion">WA</span>
<span itemprop="postalCode">98052</span>
```

The schema.org/Person page contains several examples. This [generator](http://fortseo.com/person-microdata-generator/) might be helpful.

Edited for clarification and to add Refresh info:
There are 3 "itemprop" statements in the Meta tags, these are above the itemtype and itemcope parts, which are in the body tag. So the description itemprop will not work, and both name and image will use the structured data further down the page not the meta tag ones. You need to delete the 3 'itemprop' meta tags.

**Refreshing in g+**
You can get google to re-check your page by adding a fake parameter after the page name to force it to pick up the changes, eg.  http://example.com/person.html?1 (or simple use the webmaster tools to force it to crawl the page again and pick up the new values).

Comment: I already had the itemscope and itemtype before any itemprop.  I don't see how your example does anything but add more data that I am not neccesarily interested in having inside my snippet.

Comment: I've added the answer to explain and added info on refreshing google's copy of the page. You  might want to try the latter first.