# Google share is not picking correct image while sharing

Tags: javascript, share, social-networking, facebook-opengraph

I am working on google share functionality.

I am using schema.org as explained in the answer 
[Google Plus share not picking meta tags from head](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010723/google-plus-share-not-picking-meta-tags-from-head)

```
<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
  <h1 itemprop="name">Shiny Trinket</h1>
  <img itemprop="image" src="{image-url}" />
  <p itemprop="description">Shiny trinkets are shiny.</p>
</body>
```

After this I tested this with testing tool - 
https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/

It shows correct data with testing tool. But when I share from my site it is picking up different image.

I have og tags with same information on same page. Facebook share is working correctly.

I am not finding why google picks up wrong image. Is this cache issue ?
Can anyone pls help.

Note -Image size is also as per google recommendation

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution finally its because of image sizing, try a proper proportionate image of sizing like 1600 x 900, 600x400  and see they should work.

[How to resize images proportionally / keeping the aspect ratio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971841/how-to-resize-images-proportionally-keeping-the-aspect-ratio)