# og:description and google plus not working anymore

Tags: facebook-opengraph, google-plus-one

According to [google plus documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) and [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536213/are-there-tags-to-specify-the-google-1-story-format-in-google-like-og-meta-for), the following code should add a default description when sharing:

**META:**

```
<meta property="og:title" content="TITLE HERE" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051.gif" />
<meta property="og:description" content="DESC HERE" />
<meta name="description" content="DESC HERE" />
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-annotation="inline" data-width="300"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

However, while the image and the title work, **there is no description** when sharing.
The code above is also on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Razor/BJxdk/).

Comment: It appears that this is an issue with the widget/documentation itself.