# Sharing post in Google Plus pulls author name as title

Tags: wordpress, google-plus

This is for site [bigrockinvestments.com](http://bigrockinvestments.com) . When I share any link from that site, it pulls my author name as the title instead of the post or page title. This just started happening recently.

I'm using the Yoast SEO plugin on a Genesis / AgentPress theme - all are the latest versions, as is Wordpress.

I've done a bit of research and have found some people with similar problems but I haven't yet found the exact solution or steps I'm supposed to do to resolve this.

Thanks so much in advance for your assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are there tags to specify the Google +1 story format in Google+ like og-meta for Facebook?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536213/are-there-tags-to-specify-the-google-1-story-format-in-google-like-og-meta-for)

Answer (score 1):

You have *some* schema.org metadata defined on your site, specifically it looks like you're trying to enable authorship to display your author info in Google Search. However, Google+ prefers to pull rich preview snippets from schema.org microdata and the first `itemprop="name"` is being used as the title.

What you'll likely need to do is to edit your Wordpress theme to add page-level schema.org microdata. For example, if you adjust the following elements at a high level, this should start working:

On the `<html>` element, add `itemscope` and `itemtype="type"` parameters, for example:

```
<html [other attributes] itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
```

On the `<title>` element, add:

```
<title itemtype="name">
```

The first change makes sure that your whole page is treated as a specific type of schema.org type. The second change ensures that your title is the "name" for the parent schema.org type, which is your page in this case.

[Snippet documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I'm adding Google+ authorship via the Yoast plugin. However what I can't figure out is where the schema markup is even coming from. I have another site at http://funthignsapp.com using the same parent/child themes and the markup is not there. I don't think any of the plugins I have on BRI would be adding this schema line.