# link and image in Google plus post

Tags: android, android-intent, google-plus, interactive, deep-linking

I am using this to post on Google Plus from Android.

```
    Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(this)
            .setText(tripDetails)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setContentDeepLinkId(
                    "RideShare-Post",
                    "Ride Share Buddy",
                    "Find the people around you to share your trip and save money. Chat with them and choose your best trip partner.",
                    Uri.parse("http://ridesharebuddy.com/ride_images/icon200.png"))
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://ridesharebuddy.com"))
            .getIntent();

     startActivityForResult(shareIntent, GOOGLE_PLUS_POST);
```

This is posting something like this.
[image]

I haven't specified this image's path. Still it's displaying from our server. Can I specify path for this image?

It displays proper image specified in DeepLinkId if I don't use contentUrl to set link. But I need to have link as well as proper image for this. How I can do this?

**UPDATE:**

I tried with this as answered by @demand

```
 <meta content="http://www.ridesharebuddy.com/ride_images/logo.png" itemprop="thumbnailUrl" property="og:image">
```

Still It's not displaying proper image. It still displays same.

Please guide me to correct path.

Comment: I think google get image from url itself. Someway like facebook do with opengraph (http://ogp.me/).

Comment: Oh, I find answer, look at answer from google here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536213/are-there-tags-to-specify-the-google-1-story-format-in-google-like-og-meta-for. They are using schema.org for that, and retrieve image from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google get image from url, which you posted. You can't post your own image as I know. To add image for your url you need to add image into page which you linked. Google supports opengraph and schema.org. Look at the answer from google here: [Are there tags to specify the Google +1 story format in Google+ like og-meta for Facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6536213/are-there-tags-to-specify-the-google-1-story-format-in-google-like-og-meta-for)

UPDATE:
I mean you can't set this image from your app. You must do it on your server. For example on cnn site you can find this code in html: `<meta content="http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/dam/assets/140512115559-pkg-nima-elbagir-abducted-girls-00014109-story-top.jpg" itemprop="thumbnailUrl" property="og:image">`

on this page
http://edition.cnn.com/2014/05/12/world/africa/nigeria-boko-haram-chibok-journey/index.html?hpt=hp_c2
When you share link on google plus (or Facebook), google go to your link and try to fetch this meta. If it found, google will add it to your post. How to describe it on your own website you can find on the link above.

Comment: i couldn't find how to set image url and link in post from this URL ? So if you found then can you please update answer with code here.

Comment: Thanks. What's use of content and itemprop? I guess we need to give image url in contennt that i want to display in Facebook post. But What's the use of itemprop?

Comment: Look at my answer. At the link you can find answer from google, how it works. itemprop contains field name from standard. It can be image, title etc.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I tried as you said but still it's the same. Please look at updated question with what I tried. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am specifying this image url "http://www.ridesharebuddy.com/ride_images/logo.png" but it takes this image "http://www.ridesharebuddy.com/ride_images/Enjoy.png".

Comment: Hm, very strange. I've tried this on PC, and I see this meta: <meta content="http://www.ridesharebuddy.com/ride_images/mobile.png" itemprop="thumbnailUrl" property="og:image"> And if I try to share this url, I see exactly that image

Comment: where u tried to set that ? I am trying to set that in google plus posting from android.

Comment: try to set what? I've shared link in google plus from my PC (it works the same as share from android app), and I saw image http://www.ridesharebuddy.com/ride_images/mobile.png. After that I open page ridesharebuddy.com and saw the source. And found in source this meta <meta content="ridesharebuddy.com/ride_images/mobile.png"; itemprop="thumbnailUrl" property="og:image">. Everythink works as I expect.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52668/discussion-between-demand-and-keen)

Answer (score 0):

Do this way

```
PlusShare.Builder mPlusShareBuilder = new PlusShare.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                    mPlusShareBuilder.setType("text/plain");
                    mPlusShareBuilder.setText("your Message here");
                    mPlusShareBuilder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("your Link here"));
                    Intent shareIntent = mPlusShareBuilder.getIntent();
                    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, REQUEST_CODE_SHARE);
```

Comment: Then How i can set image in post ?

Comment: set the link of image Uri.parse("your Link here") here

Comment: Then How i can set a link to somewhere else ? Let's say I want to set image from "http://ridesharebuddy.com/ride_images/icon200.png" but I want to set a link to "www.ridesharebuddy.com". How can I do that using your script ?